# issues with geting location coordinate time to time

Tags: iphone, core-location, cllocationmanager

time to time there is an issue with geting the location coordinate on my app.

I have been testing my app for location coordinate from the simulator and the iphone sitting at my home (it is not just my home, i tested it in different location (outdoor) as well with a very good network connectivity), and i see this wired behavior, i have the right co ordinate at the moment and then i send the app to the background and bring it back i get the right location co ordinate, and if i do it 8-10 times (i.e sending it to background and bringing it to foreground) once in a while after the app comes from the background  i cannot get location co ordinate, the only way to get the location co ordinate at this moment is to kill the app and then start fresh. So i am sure some thing is going wrong but I am not sure what is it.

This is what I am doing

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
   //if the time interval returned from core location is more than 30 seconds we ignore it because it might be from an old session
   if ( abs([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate: [NSDate date]]) < 30) {

        if(newLocation.coordinate.latitude != previousLocation.coordinate.latitude && newLocation.coordinate.longitude != previousLocation.coordinate.longitude){

        if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 100){
            [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
            [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]; 
   }
   else{
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
   }
```

So basically i take the newLocation only if it is not older then 30 sec, and it is not same as previous location that i have stored locally and the horizontal accuracy is less than 100 meter.  When i run it in debugger what i am observing is i get to the first if condition 3-4 times and if it fails it doesn't come after that, which means didUpdateToLocation doesn't get called at all.

Once the co ordinate meet all my criteria I do stopupdatinglocation and do startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges.

The reason i am doing startUpdatingLocation in my else block is.

For example if didUpdateToLocation got called due to the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges, i want to get the accurate location after that so i am doing startUpdatingLocation every time i don't get the right location that i am looking for  as i believe doing multiple startUpdatingLocation doesn't harm anything.

Let me know if there is something wrong in my thought process or in the code logic.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is your info.plist. You have to include the key Required Background Modes -> App registers for location updates. Without this you won't receive location updates (besides significant location changes and region monitoring) while in the background.

In the main else, you call startUpdatingLocation. While I don't believe this hurts anything, unless you are balancing it with a stopUpdatingLocation I don't believe it will do anything. Documentation says:

> Calling this method several times in succession does not automatically result in new events being generated. Calling stopUpdatingLocation in between, however, does cause a new initial event to be sent the next time you call this met

But either way, I don't think you need to tell it to startUpdating again, it will continue on it's own when the distanceFilter property is exceeded or the hardware gathers a more accurate location reading.

I don't see a closing } for your second if.

Comment: i have got the info.plist, and the problem is not with the background, the problem happens when the app comes to foreground. closing } is missing in here, but it is not in the code, otherwise my code will not compile :). So if i understand the document right it means that if i call 6 startupdatinglocation and then one stopupdatinglocation, iOS will stop updating the location it will not matter that i did 6 start and 1 stop right. now about the distanceFilter that is something that i have to look into, i haven't did any thing with it so far.

Comment: @Yogesh I'm just curious about the intended functionality. I understand your are looking for a location with a horizontal accuracy of at least 100m, and then switching to significantLocChanges. But when you talk about going into the background and coming back to the foreground repeatedly, what is the purpose of that? Is it supposed to update its location when the view appears?. And as for how you interpret the doc regarding stop/start updating location, I see it the same way but would find it better practice to balance start calls with stop calls, even if it doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: the intend is clear that every time the apps comes in the foreground update the location, and if the app remains in the foreground then update the location only if there is significantlocationchange, because there is no point in draining the battery for small location changes.

Comment: @Yogesh That would depend on the purpose of your app.